# Find a Möbius transformation that maps the unit disk to $\{x+yi \in \mathbb C: x+y \geq 0 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find a Möbius transformation that maps the unit disk to $\{x+yi \in \mathbb C: x+y \geq 0 \}$.

I was trying to use that the unit disk is $|z| < 1$, and the general form for Möbius transformation is $$f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$
Any help would appreciate!

Comment: You need a first Mobius transform to map the unit disk to the upper half plane, and then a second map $z \mapsto e^{-\pi i/4}z$ which maps the upper half plane to the half plane you described. The first map brings $0, 1, \infty$ to $0, 1, \infty$ to $1, 0, -1$, respectively.

Comment: May be easier to find the transformation that maps the unit circle to the line $x+y=0\,$, first.

Comment: $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z - 1}$ will map the unit disk to a line.

Comment: @TheoBendit: I think you mean unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Delta$ be the open unit disc and let $C=\partial\Delta$ be the unit circle.

**Hint 1.** Möbius transformations are homeomorphisms of the Riemann sphere onto itself, and therefore if $m$ is a Möbius transformation then $m(\Delta)$ is *almost* determined by $m(\partial\Delta)=m(C)$; meanwhile, $C$ is a circle and the boundary of the required image region is a straight line.

**Hint 2.** If you want to construct a Möbius map that sends three chosen points $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ to three other chosen points $A,B,C,$ one way to proceed is as follows: write down
$$m(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},$$
use the fact that $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ map to $A,B,C$ to put constraints on $a,b,c,d,$ and then find a solution to the resulting linear equations.

**Answer.**

> We choose the points $1,i,-1\in C$ and we want to construct a Möbius map $m$ 
>  sending these three points to the points $1-i,0,-1+i$ on the line $x+y=0.$
>  After following the advice of Hint 2 above, we might arrive at the candidate
>  $$m(z) = \frac{2(z-i)}{(1-i)z+(1+i)}.$$
>  So this Möbius map sends the unit circle $C$ to the line $x+y=0.$ This means 
>  that $m(\Delta)$ is either $x+y>0$ or $x+y<0.$ To see which, we examine 
>  $m(0)$: we have
>  $$m(0)=\frac{2(-i)}{1+i} = -1-i,$$
>  so we see that $\operatorname{Re}{(m(0))}+\operatorname{Im}{(m(0))}<0.$ This 
>  means that the Möbius map we have come up with is not quite what we are 
>  looking for, but in this case it is easy to fix this: just take $n(z)=-m(z)$ 
>  instead. That is, a Möbius map that fits the required condition is
>  $$n(z)=\frac{2(z-i)}{(-1+i)z-(1+i)}.$$

Comment: Note that hint 2 describes one way to construct such a Möbius map, but this is not the only way (and sometimes it might well be awful). Another way is to construct two maps, a map $T$ which sends $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ to $0,1,\infty,$ and a map $S$ which sends $A,B,C$ to $0,1,\infty.$ These are easy to write down. Then compute $S^{-1}T$; this is probably best done by exploiting the analogy with matrix multiplication.

Comment: To the definition in my textbook, a unit disk means $|z|<1$, which is an open ball. So if we map $|z|=1$ to $x+y=0$, would there be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: @Nan: The circle splits the plane into two sections, an inside and an outside; the line $x+y=0$ also splits the plane into two sections, the half-planes $x+y>0$ and $x+y<0.$ The only problem that might arise in mapping the unit circle to the line is that you need to make sure that your map sends the disc to the correct half-plane.

Comment: Thanks! So to my understanding, we can only map $|z| \leq 1$ to $x+y \geq 0$, since we need to map a closed set to a closed set because $f$ is continuous here. I am not sure whether I got the right idea.

Comment: Or map the $|z|<1$ to $x+y >0$ similarly.

Comment: Given both comments, I think you understand. The disc is always mapped to one of the two half-planes because Möbius maps are so nice. The problem therefore consists of finding Möbius maps which map the boundary circle correctly and then making sure the interior maps to the correct half-plane.

Answer (score 2):

The common idea in this and one of your previous recent questions is the upper half plane. The Mobius transfrmations of the upper half plane to itself are those $\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with real $a,b,c,d$ and $ad-bc > 0.$ Worth remembering.

Going back and forth between the upper half plane and the standard unit disk are inverse mappings
$$  \frac{z+i}{iz+1} $$ and
$$ \frac{iz+1}{z + i}.  $$
The first one $  \frac{z+i}{iz+1} $ takes $0$ from the interior of the unit disk to $i$ in the interior of the upper half plane. Also, the unit circle goes to the real line, as $1 \rightarrow 1 \; , \; $ $-1 \rightarrow -1 \; , \; $ $-i \rightarrow 0 \; , \; $ $i \rightarrow \infty \; . \; $

The second one does the reverse.

We also know that the two transformations are inverse mappings because the product of the associated matrices is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, therefore the identity mapping ($2iz/(2i) = z$).

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & i \\
i & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
i & 1 \\
1 & i \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2i & 0 \\
0 & 2i \\
\end{array}
\right) = 2 i
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$